# the concatenation of bivariate iid

Tags: probability, random-variable, signal-processing

suppose that $X \sim N\left( {0,{\sigma ^2}{I_2}} \right)$ is a bivariate white noise, and the samples ${X_1}, \cdots ,{X_N}$ are drawn from it, if we define the new random variable $Y$ with its samples ${Y_t} = \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{{X_t}}\\
 \vdots \\
{{X_{t + n - 1}}}
\end{array}} \right]$, $t = 1, \cdots ,N - n + 1$,
what distribution would $Y$ follow and what is its covariance matrix

Comment: Your notation is not clear.

Comment: how is that , what is not clear?

Comment: You did not define $n$. Is the idea that you are stacking the (column) vectors $X_i$?

Comment: yes basically, n is finite ofcourse, lets assume it n=2

Comment: what would be the answer

Answer (score 0):

You have some iid random vectors, each is bivariate $\mathcal{N}_2(0,I)$ which you then are stacking as one vector of some length (depending on some $n$ you did not explain.) Then you have a vector of iid standard normals, of some length. Mean vector is zero, covariance matrix identity matrix of some dimension. There is nothing I can see in the question but play on notation. (maybe I misunderstood ...)

Comment: are you sure covariance matrix is identity because the sample covariance $R = \frac{1}{N-n+1}\sum\limits_{i = 1}^{N-n+1} {{Y_i}Y_i^T} $ does not seem to give me identity, thats why im confused